# What does it mean for a function to be Mapping from $\mathbb R^k$ Space to $\mathbb R^1$ Space

Tags: linear-algebra

If a function maps from $\mathbb R^k$ Space to say $\mathbb R^1$ Space

Does that mean Function takes on $K$ variables and

spits out a variable?

Comment: It means the function takes in a single variable, but that variable is a point in ${\bf R}^k$ (and then gives out a single number).

Comment: You can interpret the function as one that takes on $k$ real variables and spits out one real variable, as well as one that takes on a single $\Bbb R^k$ variable and spits out an $\Bbb R^1$ one.

Answer (score 2):

It means that the function takes $k$ *real numbers* (which correspond to *one point* in $\mathbb R^k$) and gives you one real number (which is a point in $\mathbb R$).